# Create a vCPU that consists multible CPUs

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, cpu-usage, virtualization, vcpu

Short question and hopefully a positive answer:

Is it possible to create a virtual CPU that consists from multible real cores?
So lets say you have a 4x3.5 GHz CPU, can you create a vCPU that is 1x14GHz ?

Why do it? 
If there is a software which is heavily CPU using, but can just use one thread, it would boost up the program.

I am not very advanced with hardware tech, but I guess there is no way to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: No..Its not possible. I think you need to understand the meaning of X g/mhz at which cpu cycle runs. As far as I understand, each vcpu corresponds to single real CPU behind the scene. Also One thread can only run on one physical CPU at one time. so if program is single thread, it has to stick to one CPU only and each physical CPU can only at one frequency. But cpus can be configured for cpu cycles, if particular cpu allows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So lets say you have a 4x3.5 GHz CPU, can you create a vCPU that is 1x14GHz ?

No. As the expression goes -- [nine women cannot make a baby in one month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27s_law).

Each instruction executed by a virtual CPU can potentially be dependent on anything that previously happened on that CPU. There's no way to run an instruction (or a group of instructions) before all of the previous instructions have been completed. That leaves no room for another physical CPU to speed things up.